# Route conflict in ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have two different controllers and each one with its configured routes. To explain my problem, I will exemplify:

ProdutoController

```
[Route("v1/empresas/{idConexao}/produtos/{id}")]
```

ProdutoCategoriaController

```
[Route("v1/empresas/{idConexao}/produtos/categorias")]
```

When doing a GET on the route "v1/empresas/{idConexao}/produtos/categorias" using postman I get the following error message:

> Multiple controller types were found that match the URL. This can happen if attribute routes on multiple controllers match the requested URL

But if I comment on route "v1/empresas/{idConexao}/produtos/{id}" I can do a get on route "v1/empresas/{idConexao}/produtos/categorias" and vice versa.

Does anyone know how i can solve this problem? I see no sense in this error

Comment: Because `"categorias"` is a perfectly legitimate Id unless you specify otherwise. Look at the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#route-constraints

Comment: If your `id` is always numeric, you can mark it as `[Route("v1/empresas/{idConexao}/produtos/{id:int}")]`, which should allow both routes to work. See the documentation that Aluan posted for other constraint types.  As long as you pick one that "categorias" doesn't fit, it should work.

Comment: Your both routes are working get http verb in same controller name produtos. you have specify same controller name in both route and this is reason. This will work if you change your route like                                             [Route("v1/empresas/{idConexao}/produtos/{id}")]

[Route("v1/empresas/{idConexao}/ProdutoCategoria/categorias")]

Comment: @AluanHaddad Haddad reading the documentation I was able to better understand how route restrictions work

Comment: Glad that was useful. There are a lot of ways you can make this work and I did not want to suggest one arbitrarily without more information, like the type of Id.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is tath both path match same route if {id} attribute is a string.

Asp.net cannot difference of "categories" is a id param or part of path

To solve this, you can use route constrains, to make more especific path.

For example, you can define type of param id like a int or guid.

```
[Route("v1/empresas/{idConexao}/produtos/{id:int}")]
```

this way you can call api with and responses should be those:

- v1/empresas/{idConexao}/produtos/categorias -- Ok 200
- v1/empresas/{idConexao}/produtos/1 --> OK 200
- v1/empresas/{idConexao}/produtos/anotherString --> NotFound 400

You can read about route constrains here: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#route-constraint-reference

I hope this is usefull!

Best regards